# Invalid operands to binary in my 'NumberSize' function

Tags: c

I have created a function that is supposed to take the numbers in my linked list and determine which one is the smallest number and which one is the largest number. I created a while loop that is supposed to take each number and compare it to the next. 'newNumber' is the current number and 'next' should be the number next in the list. I am having trouble understanding how to call the current and next number. My while loop is also infinite is it because, I am referring to the numbers again in determine?

```
double NumberSize(NewNumber *start){

NewNumber *determine = start;
double SecondNumber =0;
double FirstNumber = 0;
while(determine != NULL){
    FirstNumber = determine->newNum;
    SecondNumber = determine->next;

    if(FirstNumber < SecondNumber){
        printf("The biggest number is:\n", SecondNumber);
    }else{
        printf("The smallest number is:\n", FirstNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `if(decide < determine)` supposed to mean? `decide` is a `double`, and `determine` is a pointer. What does it mean to compare them? Your loop is infinite because you do `while(determine)`, and then never change the value of `determine`, so the loop condition never becomes false. You appear to be wanting to calculate the biggest and smallest numbers, but you set `smallNumber` and `bigNumber` to zero at the start of your function, and then never change them again. You seem to be just guessing. You can't successfully approach programming in this manner.

Comment: @ericeric the method you use to print the nodes, compute the average or, in this case, look for the biggest/smallest entry is always the same: you walk through the list and do something with the entries. That means you can reuse that part for everything listed above.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I have an idea on how to get the while loop to no longer be infinite.  I would need two variables, one to store the largest number and one to store the smallest number?  I would also need to create and if statement comparing the first in the list to the next?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to step through the list. Using on of the solutions for the average:

```
void NumberSize(NewNumber * start)
{
  double num = 0.0;

  double biggest;
  double smallest;
  int flag = 0;

  NewNumber *temp = start;
  // set start values
  if(tmp != NULL){
     biggest = temp->newNum;
     smallest = temp->newNum;
     tmp = tmp->next;
     flag = 1;
  }

  // while temp is not NULL
  while (temp) {
    // get number from current node
    num = temp->newNum;
    // if that number is bigger than "biggest"
    if (num > biggest) {
      // exchange "biggest" with "num"
      biggest = num;
    }
    // do it the same way for the smallest number
    else if (num < smallest) {
      smallest = num;
    }
    // here is the forgotten line:
    // go to the next node
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  if(flag){
    // no returns, just printing
    printf("The smallest number is: \n", smallest);
    printf("The biggest number is: \n", biggest);
  } else {
    puts("list empty");
  }
}
```

Comment: If all the numbers are above zero, this code will incorrectly show the smallest as zero. Similarly, if they're all negative, it will incorrectly show the biggest as zero. You also should take another look at your `printf()` calls.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths yes, that's correct, but what is wrong with the printf() calls...oh...wanted to use variables from caller (`void NumberSize(NewNumber * start, double *biggest, double *smallest)`) frogot to change it back, will edit. Or delete completely. Don't want to suffer from helping others.